# Jest with React Testing Library - locate a radio box without id and fire click event

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have an html piece in my code and trying to locate the radio box and firing the click event to test changes. Since it does not have id I am not able to find a way to locate it to trigger the click event

```
<div>
    <label class="form-control__radio radio__label__pos__right " id="anyAmount" data-testid="my-radio-">
      <span class="input__container">
         <input type="radio" id="" name="test" class="" value="Anyamount">
      </span>
      <span class="label__container">
          <span id="anyAmount--text" class="label__text" tabindex="-1">Any amount</span> 
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="form-control__radio radio__label__pos__right " id="customAmounts" data-testid="my-radio-">
        <span class="input__container">
            <input type="radio" id="" name="test" class="" value="Customamount">
        </span>
        <span class="label__container">
            <span id="customAmounts--text" class="label__text" tabindex="-1">Custom amount</span>
        </span>
    </label>
</div>
```

This is my test case

```
 it('renders the custom amount section when transaction amount custom amount radio checked ', () => {
   const { getByTestId, container } = render(<mycomponent  /> )
   const minAmountContainer = container.querySelector('#amountfrominput')
   const maxAmountContainer = container.querySelector('#amounttoinput')
   const radioCustomAmount = getByTestId('my-radio-')
   fireEvent.click(radioCustomAmount)
   expect(minAmountContainer).toBeInTheDocument()
   expect(maxAmountContainer).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

The error I received was  Found multiple elements by: [data-testid="my-radio-"] which is obvios.

Please note that I cannot change the HTML as the html is generated by a library method which I do not have any control, so giving id or making any changes to html is not possible.

Looking for suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query multiple elements, using

> `getAllBy...`: Returns an array of all matching nodes for a query, and throws an error if no elements match

[image]

See [Types of Queries](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#types-of-queries)

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export const Mycomponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label className="form-control__radio radio__label__pos__right " id="anyAmount" data-testid="my-radio-">
        <span className="input__container">
          <input type="radio" id="" name="test" className="" value="Anyamount" />
        </span>
        <span className="label__container">
          <span id="anyAmount--text" className="label__text" tabIndex={-1}>
            Any amount
          </span>
        </span>
      </label>
      <label className="form-control__radio radio__label__pos__right " id="customAmounts" data-testid="my-radio-">
        <span className="input__container">
          <input type="radio" id="" name="test" className="" value="Customamount" />
        </span>
        <span className="label__container">
          <span id="customAmounts--text" className="label__text" tabIndex={-1}>
            Custom amount
          </span>
        </span>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { fireEvent, screen, render } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import React from 'react';
import { Mycomponent } from '.';

describe('73145490', () => {
  it('renders the custom amount section when transaction amount custom amount radio checked ', () => {
    render(<Mycomponent />);
    const radioCustomAmount = screen.getAllByTestId('my-radio-');
    fireEvent.click(radioCustomAmount[0]);
  });
});
```